# Hypothesis testing for the (Pearson) correlation coefficient

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, mathematical-statistics

[image]

I don't understand why we have to assume ρ=0 in to get the probability density function? If I say null hypothesis p is something like 0.3, I can still use the probability density function, can't I?

Answer (score 4):

This distribution is obtained with the density transformation technique from the test statistic

$$T = \frac{\hat{\rho} \sqrt{n-2} }{ \sqrt{1-\hat{\rho}^2}}$$

which follows the t-distribution with $n-2$ degrees of freedom. The reason that it works solely for $H_0:\rho = 0$ is that this is a test for independence for a bivariate normal distribution and hence *it was derived under the assumption that $\rho = 0$* (through a likelihood ratio).

Don't worry, though, there are still ways to test arbitrary null hypotheses. I believe the most popular approach is the use of [Fisher's z-transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation). That is, for $H_0: \rho = \rho_0$ you may construct the test-statistic

$$T = \frac{1}{2} \frac{ \log\frac{1+\hat{\rho}}{1-\hat{\rho}} - \log\frac{1+\rho_0}{1-\rho_0}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-3}}} $$

which looks more complicated than what we are used to but follows the standard normal distribution under the null hypothesis. So no need for the annoying t-distribution.

Comment: @whoisit If this is what you wanted, you can upvote and accept it as the correct one.